# Prove that if 1 is a linear combination of two integers a, b, then a and b are relatively prime.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that if 1 is a linear combination of two integers $a, b$, then $a$ and $b$
are relatively prime. Use only basic divisibility properties. (Do not use GCDLC).

I can only figure out how to prove this using the GCDLC.

Comment: What is the GCDLC?

Comment: greatest common divisor linear combination theorem

Comment: But the _proof_ of the GCDLC will solve this. So what you're asking for here is basically a proof of GCDLC, as I see it.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ will necessary divide any linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $ma+nb=1$, and that $a$ and $b$ are not coprime, i.e. there is an integer $d>1$ which divides both $a$ and $b$.

If $d$ divides $a$ and $b$ then there exist integers $s$ and $t$ for which $a=ds$ and $b=dt$. In that case

$$ma+nb=1 \iff m(ds)+n(dt)=1 \iff d(ms+nt)=1$$

It follows that $d$ divides $1$. The only positive number that divides $1$ is $1$ itself, meaning that $d=1$.

Hence, the only positive number dividing both $a$ and $b$ is $1$, i.e. $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: This doesn't use basic divisibility properties.

Comment: @Bernard Why not?

Comment: Fun fact: you can take away "assume that $\gcd(a,b)>1$" from the start and "this is a contradiction since" from the end of this proof, and it will still work just fine. No need for an actual contradiction here.

Comment: @Arthur Explain...

Comment: "Assume that $ma+nb=1$ and $d=\gcd(a,b)$. (proof details). This means that $d\mid 1$, so $d=1$." is a full proof. Adding a contradiction just for the sake of it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Arthur That is a fun fact :o)

Comment: @Fly by Night: Existence of g.c.d.  is already a comparatively sophisticated result.

Comment: @Bernard That's fair enough. I've changed it so there is no mention of $\gcd$.

Comment: That's better. However, you don't need to say you prove ‘by contradiction’. It's not a real roof by contradiction. It will be shorter to explain why, if $ma+nb=1$, $d$ is necessarily equal to $1$.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure that I agree. I assume that $a$ and $b$ are not coprime and then get a contradiction. Sure, it could be streamlined, but it is a valid PbC.

Comment: I didn't say there's an error in your proof, which is perfectly correct. I just think it's an unnecessary use of contradiction. Such proofs are very unnatural to beginners and, personally, I tend to avoid them if it's possible. Try to change it in the way I suggest, and you'll it requires very few modifications in the phrasing of the proof.

Comment: @Bernard I've made the changes you suggested

Answer (score 0):

the combination possible is a-b(for any two consecutive integers with a>b).
a-b=1 so a=b+1, which means that a and b are consecutive integers.then one must be even and other must be odd, since odd and even numbers are coprime thus so are a and b.

Comment: alternatively you can say that number that divide a and b will divide any combination of a and b,here combination of a and b is 1, so the number that divide both a and b also divide 1, so it is one i.e, 1 is hcf of a and b and thus a and b are coprime